# How to test apps on older builds of Windows 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10

I have an app that targets Windows 10 build 10240, but my local machine has the latest update.

for phone I see there are various emulators in Visual Studio. Is there a way to test an app on older versions of Windows 10 desktop?

(I know one way is to actually find an older windows and run it on a virtual machine, but I want an easier way)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my last comment on your other question, you just need to change your target version from whatever to 10240 and run the app. If there are unsupported stuff, you get compile time error. If you use xaml stuff that's not available in 10240, you should get that wavy line to indicate you that it's not available on 10240, assuming you have the latest VS installed.

Comment: @JustinXL ohh thank you I got it. I wonder what's the use of selecting a `minimum version` if the app won't run on it.

Comment: So you know which API is not supported in 10240. If it runs fine, that means it's working OK on 10240.

Comment: @JustinXL but my app targets AU, and minimum is set to 10240. I never knew some resources aren't available in 10240 until the app crashed for some users who actually had 10240.. no compile time errors were shown

Comment: That's why you need to reduce your target version to 10240 to find out what resources and even APIs are not supported in 10240 by running your app and getting compile-time errors. When you set your min version to 10240, you have committed that your app will run on it, so you need to test against it to make sure that your app runs OK.

Comment: download the ISOs for the older versions, install a VM and sideload the apps and test them

Comment: I thought Visual Studio will check compatibility of all the versions in between automatically. Thanks @JustinXL .

Comment: I just wrote you an answer. Hopefully it's a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thought I should write an answer just to make it clearer.

Currently, if your target version is *15063* and min version is *10240*, you do get some benefits like what's shown in the following picture -

[image]

Properties like `FocusVisualMargin` will be highlighted as

> The property ‘FocusVisualMargin’ on type ‘ListViewItem’ is not
>   available in the target platform minimum version (10.0.10240.0)
>   supported by this project.

However, resources like `ListViewItemForeground` are also not available in *10240* but they are not highlighted. Same as in the following picture -

[image]

This `SetImplicitShowAnimation` API is also not available in *10240* but it's not highlighted.

This tells me Visual Studio doesn't not fully recognise everything in each version. This may change in the future, but for the time being, it's just a lot safer to either run it on a *10240* machine, or reduce the target version to *10240*, then run and test.

If you want to create *Version Adaptive Code*, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code).

Comment: Where do we set target version?